Can restriction map trivialize a　element in $H^1(G_K,M)$ by finite extension?
Let $K$ be a field and $G_K=\text{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$ be absolute Galois group of $K$. Let $M$ be a finite $G_K$ module.
For finite Galois extension $L/K$, let $H^1(G_K,M)\to H^1(G_L,M)$ be restriction map of Galois cohomology.
Take $f\in H^1(G_K,M)$. Is it true that there exists some finite extension $L/K$ such that $res(f)$ becomes trivial map.
Since $M$ is finite, image of $f : G_K\to M$ is finite set, say , $\{m_1,m_2,・・・, m_n\}$. There exists $L/K$: finite such that $\text{Gal}(\overline{K}/L)$ acts tricially for all $m_i$. I don't see why  $f\mid_{{G_L}} : G_L\to M$ is trivia map. I should take more large extension $L/K$ but I cannot find it.
Thank you in advance.

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}
\DeclareMathOperator{\res}{res}$
Here is a simple explicit construction of such an $L$.
Since $M$ is finite, the map $G_K\to \Aut M$ factors through a finite quotient. In other words, there is a finite extension $L'/K$ such that $G_{L'}$ acts trivially on $M$. You then have $H^1(G_{L'},M)=\Hom(G_{L'},M)$. Now $\res_{L'/K}f$ is a group homomorphism with image in a finite group, so if we call its kernel $G_L$, then the fixed field of $G_L$ is a finite extension $L$ of $L'$ such that $\res_{L/K}f$ is trivial.
